# Using new with an object

Tags: c++, class, object, pointers

I'm learning how to make programs using Qt. My question is about 3 things i'm not very good at: pointers, objects and "new()".

Look: (Dialog is a class)

```
//start of code...
...

private: 
    Dialog *mDialog; //Dialog is a class 

...

void MainWindow::on_activationNew_window_triggered()
{
    mDialog = new Dialog(this); // Explain me this "this"
}

...

//end of code
```

Explain me how that line works, what "this" does (or is) exacly.

All i know is mDialog is a class for a window, and when the scope ends, the window closes, so he makes that pointer and uses new, because it will use a stack memory, that means it won't close the window when the scope ends.

If you want to watch the part of the video he is making and explaining this (maybe i wasnt clear enough) here is the video (Start at 8:07):

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wUH_gu2HdQE&feature=relmfu

Tnks for any help!

Comment: If anything it would be "heap" _not_ "stack", and even then I hesitate to bring these implementation specifics into things. Time to re-read your C++ book?!

Comment: yes... its the oposite of what i said!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others have said, "this" refers to the object from where it's called. Just like:

```
class X {
  public:
    int y;
};
```

If you write

```
X obj_X;
```

obj_X will have a variable of the name "this". It will be used to access itself, and is most used in passing a class object to another method/class/anything.

Now, about Qt :)

Every Qt Object has a parent. That's used for *a lot* of Qt's inner workings, but it's like an object owns another. To specify what is the parent object, and what's the child, you send the parent's address to the child's constructor.

So, you could also do
    Dialog mDialog(this);

This means that thing has nothing to do with the "new" operator. So let's get to it:

```
Dialog mDialog(/*< constructor parameters >*/); << HERE!
```

"this" is sent to mDialog's constructor, to specify that it has a parent. And it's parent is the object pointed by "this". You could also do it like

```
Dialog mDialog(); // In which case mDialog has NO parent, because 0 parameteres went to the constructor
```

It's that simple :). Get your c++ book and read more about constructors, and also get more Qt tutorials on the internet. Good luck!

Comment: "Dialog mDialog(/*< constructor parameters >*/); << HERE!"
you cant do that, because it would allocate a stack memmory, and when the scope of function ends, the window would end too!

Comment: I wasn't talking about that, I was talking about the fact that the "THIS" parameter has nothing to do with the "new" operator.

Comment: `Dialog mDialog();` doesn't send _anything_ to a constructor or even invoke one, because [it doesn't instantiate a `Dialog`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse).

Answer (score 2):

"this" is a c++ concept....when working inside of an object (in your example MainWindow), this is a pointer to that same object.

So say I create a class called Dog in c++, in my methods I can refer to the current object as this.

```
class Dog
{
public: 
Dog(); //default constructor
Dog(const Dog&); //copy constructor

};

Dog::Dog(const Dog& original)
{
if (&original != this)
 //do whatever;
}
```

Comment: in my case, whats the current object?

Comment: A constructor may not `return` anything.

Comment: Good point.  Maybe I should have not used a constructor as an example.  Thanks for noticing my error.

Answer (score 1):

A (non-static) member function is a function called with an implicit parameter of class type.  In the definition

```
void MainWindow::on_activationNew_window_triggered()
{ //...
}
```

the `MainWindow::` means the function being defined is a member function of class `MainWindow`.  In a (non-static) member function, the keyword `this` is a pointer to that implicit argument.  (Also, if you just name a class member like `member`, it's really short for `this->member`.)

So in the function you quoted, the type of `this` is `MainWindow* const`.

It looks like the code is passing a pointer to the `MainWindow` to the `Dialog` constructor.

Answer (score 1):

`this` refers to a pointer that can be used in non-static member functions belonging to a class (or union or struct).  It points to the object for which the member function is called (in this case, `MainWindow`).

The reason why it is being passed into the constructor of `Dialog` is due to Qt's object model.  Refer to the following documentation for more information on this:

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/objecttrees.html